# Big O notation and convergence of fraction

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

Let $0 < \delta < r < 1$, where $r$ is fixed and $\delta $ not fixed, and let $f$ be a function defined on the integers. Assume further that for every $\delta$ there is some constant $0 < c_\delta < \infty$

$$ \frac{f(n)}{n^{(r-\delta)^{-1}}} \longrightarrow c_\delta, \quad \text{as } n \to \infty.$$

I want to show that: $f(n) = O (n^{1/r +\delta})$ for all $\delta > 0$.

I think (please correct me, if I am wrong), that from the convergence above we get $f(n) = O(n^{(r-\delta)^{-1}})$ for all $0 < \delta< r$.

**Edit**:
Ok, here my try: **Claim**: $f(n) = O(n^{(r-\delta)^{-1}})$ for all $0 < \delta < r$.

Let $\epsilon >0$. $\forall \delta > 0 \ \exists N_\delta$ s.t. $ \forall n \geq N_\delta:$ $\vert \frac{f(n)}{n^{(r-\delta)^{-1}}} - c_\delta \vert < \epsilon$. Then, set $M := \max_\delta \{c_\delta\} + \epsilon$ which satisfies $f(n) \leq M n^{(r-\delta)^{-1}}$ for all $n \geq \max_\delta \{ N_\delta\}$. This should prove the claim. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

The claim is not true. Take $r=1/2$ and $\delta=1/4$ and $f(n) = n^{(r-\delta)^{-1}} = n^4$. Then $n^{\frac{1}{r} + \delta} = n^{2.25}$ but $n^4 \notin O(n^{2.25})$.

More generally, the issue is that $\frac{1}{r-\delta} > \frac{1}{r} + \delta$ for $\delta > 0$, so $n^{(r-\delta)^{-1}}$ grows much faster than $n^{\frac{1}{r} + \delta}$.

Comment: Thanks, do you also know whether what I wrote at the bottom is true?

Comment: @MATH101 Yes, if $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \to c$ then $f(n) = O(g(n))$.

Comment: Then, I am wondering why $f(n) = O (n^{1/r+ \delta})$ is not true (I understand your counter example). The statement $f(n) = O (n^{(r-\delta)^{-1}})$ is strongest for $\delta$ very small. In particular, $\delta = 0$, if allowed, would be strongest. Similarly, the same goes for the statement $f(n) = O (n^{1/r+ \delta})$, and, if $\delta = 0$ was to be allowed, they would be identical. (?)

Comment: @MATH101 See my edit. They are the same when $\delta = 0$, but when $\delta > 0$, $f$ grows faster than $n^{\frac{1}{r} + \delta}$.

Comment: Thanks! I don't want to be annoying... But can't I, for any $0 < \delta < r$ that I pick, find a $\tilde \delta > 0$ s.t. $ \frac{1}{r-\delta} \leq \frac{1}{r} + \tilde \delta$?

Comment: @MATH101 Yes that's true, but I was under the impression that the problem was only considering the case $\delta = \tilde{\delta}$.

Comment: Ah ok, I might have not written it in a clever/correct way. Let's put it this way: For all $0 < \delta < r$, we have the mentioned convergence and therefore, $f(n) = O(n^{(r-\delta)^{-1}})$ (for all $0 < \delta < r$). This is equivalent to $f(n) = O(n^{1/r + \epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. Is this correct then?